# $bc$ CFT commutator of Virasoro and modes of ghost number current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory, conformal-field-theory

Given the ghost current $j(z)=-:b(z)c(z):$ and the stress tensor $T(z) = \colon \partial b c \colon  - \lambda \partial \colon b c \colon$, one may obtain the following commutation relation (via the usual method of inverting the modes and performing closed line integrals, using radial ordering and OPE expansions etc.):

It is not hard to show that one obtains

$$[L_n,J_m]=-mJ_{n+m}+\frac{1}{2}(1-2\lambda)n(n+1)\delta_{m+n,0}.$$

Using the above relation, I tried to set $m=-n$ so as to obtain the normal order constant for $J_{0}$ (which can be shown to be equal to $-1/2$, as is discussed for example in this post: [About the conserved charge for the ghost number current in $bc$ conformal field theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/72257)).

My question is therefore twofold:

1. I have not been able to show that the normal order constant is $-\frac{1}{2}$ using the commutation relation above - should this be a possible way to derive the constant or is there some fundamental reason why this won't work? The method given in Polchinski seems to be quite a bit more subtle, which is why I ask, as can be seen from user Oбжорoв's answer in the post above, that is why I am looking for a 'simpler' derivation.
2. Disregarding the issue of calculating the normal order constant, when I plug in the mode expansion of $L_n$ and $J_{-n}$ into the left-hand side, I seem to obtain the non-normal ordered expression $L_{0}$ and nothing else - which does not match the right-hand side of the commutator.

Does anyone have an idea as to what's going on?

For completeness, here's the mode expansion for the generators that I used:

$$L_n=-\sum_{m}(\lambda n-m): b_n c_{n-m}:+\frac{1}{2}\lambda(1-\lambda)$$

and

$$J_{-n}=-: \sum_{m}b_m c_{-n-m}:-a \delta_{n,0}$$

(note that although the commutator relation was calculated using normal ordered $L_n$, as far as I'm aware here it shouldn't matter which ordering I use since they all differ by a constant which will drop in the commutator).